# Modifier information in the Order Information Email template

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible to access the modifier information in an email template?

I want to tell the costumer what they baught, i can tell them the product name but not the modifier

i can tell them this for example:

Hey you baught the cool t-shirt!

but i cannot tell them this:

Hey you baught the cool t-shirt in the color YELLOW!

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your email template you can do something along the lines of

```
{items}
Item - {title} - {modifiers}{modifier_value}{/modifiers}, 
Qty - {item_qty}, 
Item Total - {item_total}
{/items}
```

All of the variables available in the orders tag pair ([link](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/orders_tag.html) should be available to you in the email templates. The orders tag allows for all of the [checkout variables](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html) plus the additional variables for the order details.

Comment: Thank you! You were right! The correct code for this was:
{modifiers}{modifier_value}{/modifiers}

Comment: Aww yes `{modifier_value}` is indeed what you would want to use to output the users selection when adding the item to the cart. I have amended answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, totally possible. The detail isn't held in the orders channel, usually just the purchased items channel.

So, if you open the a new channel entries tag and pass the search:purchased_item_order_id="{order_id}" - it will then give you access to the channel fields in that entries loop.

Comment: I believe he is using Exp-resso Store instead of CartThrob